# Конструктор внутреннего класса в лямбде и Java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, java-stream

Вроде простейший кусок кода, а я себе уже всю голову сломал, что в нем не так:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {

    private static class C {

        private abstract class A {
            protected final String S;

            public A(String s) {
                this.S = s;
            }

            public A(Stream<? extends A> s) {
                this.S = s.map(a -> a.S).reduce((s1, s2) -> s1.concat(s2)).orElse(null);
            }
        }
        private class B extends A {
            public B(ArrayList<String> b) {
                super(b.stream().map(bb -> new B(bb)));
            }

            public B(String s) {
                super(s);
            }
        }


        public C() {
           B b = new B(new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Ни IDEA, ни NetBeans на него не ругаются и он компилируется, однако в рантайме вылезает следующее:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    test/Test$C$B.lambda$new$0(Ltest/Test$C;Ljava/lang/String;)Ltest/Test$C$B; @5: getfield
  Reason:
    Type 'test/Test$C' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'test/Test$C$B'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'test/Test$C', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { uninitialized 0, uninitialized 0, 'test/Test$C' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 0759 2ab4 0001 2bb7 0008 b0       

    at test.Test$C.<init>(Test.java:34)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:41)
C:\Users\<тут пути>\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Если судить по строке location и reason, то получается, что конструктор B() в лямбде в 23 строке в своем теле вызывает super не от Test$C$B, а от Test$C, и поэтому не может его инициализировать. Но это же совсем бредятина какая-то.

Comment: Попробуй в классах объявить конструкторы по умолчанию еще, хотя бы с пустым телом. Хотя бы в  А. (Возможно в B тоже понадобится....... но это не точно) в С не нужно

Comment: Но как в конструкторе без параметров инициализировать final переменные у класса A?

Comment: не надо ничего инициализировать. написал же **с пустым телом**

Comment: `public A(){};` и `public B(){};` ничего не поменяли, к тому же IDE их подчеркивает и правильно делает.

Comment: Упростите пример. `B b = new B("aaaa");` работает? Если убрать все перегруженные конструкторы работает? `super(b.stream());` работает?

Comment: JVM ругается на лямбду в методе  `public B(ArrayList<String> b)`, причем всегда, даже если этим конструктором не пользовались. Если его удалить и в конструкторе класса C написать не `B b = new B(new ArrayList<>());`, а `B b = new B("aaaa")` то работать будет, а если этот конструктор вернуть, то не будет. Причем в это все падает в runtime, а не compile time. Если же избавиться от этой лямбды так:  `super(b.stream())`, то тоже работает.

Comment: Причем все лечится вынесением классов A и B из C. Или добавлением к ним модификтора static.

Comment: Про статик я знаю, да. Но надо, чтобы классы A и B имели доступ к полям экземпляра класса C, в обоих вариантах пропадет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отличие от многих подобных громких заявлений, вы действительно наткнулись на [баг в JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178444). Его починили, но фикс войдет только в релиз Java 10. Хорошая новость для вас в том, что есть довольно безобидный костыль:

```
public B(ArrayList<String> b) {
    super(b.stream().map(bb -> C.this.new B(bb)));
}
```

---

> Если судить по строке location и reason, то получается, что конструктор B() в лямбде в 23 строке в своем теле вызывает super не от Test$C$B, а от Test$C

Нет, все даже хитрее.

### Что вообще произошло?

На этапе компиляции ваша лямбда `bb -> new B(bb)` превратилась в синтетический `static` метод условно следующего вида:

```
private synthetic static B lambda$new$0(C c$this, String s) {
    C this = getFieldValue(c$this, "B.this$0:LC"); // да, выглядит странно
    return new B(thisC, s);
}
```

что соответствует фактическому байткоду:

```
0: new #7 // class C$B
3: dup
4: aload_0
5: getfield #1 // Field this$0:LC;    ← Тот самый getfield из ошибки
8: aload_1
9: invokespecial #8 // Method "<init>":(LC;Ljava/lang/String;)V
12: areturn
```

*Что это еще за `c$this`?* Как вы, вероятно, знаете экземпляры внутреннего класса всегда связаны с экземпляром внешнего. И ссылка на внешний класс передается в конструктор неявным параметром. Т.е. синтаксис скрывает это, но в конструкторы класса `B` первым параметром передается ссылка на `C`. Когда конструктор внутреннего класса используется в лямбде, к ней тоже добавляется неявный параметр, через который эта самая ссылка на `C` протаскивается в конструктор `B`.

Из-за бага компилятора, он делает лишние некорректные действия, пытаясь получить внутренне поле `B.this$0` на экземпляре `C`.

*Но я же даже не вызывал ни эту лямбду, ни конструктор, в котором она используется?* Все верно. Ошибка [`java.lang.VerifyError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html) бросается до выполнения кода, еще на этапе загрузки класса.

Когда JVM в конструкторе `public C()` видит создание экземпляра `B`,  загрузчик классов грузит класс `B`. При этом производится проверка байткода всего класса. Верификатор находит в байткоде метода `lambda$new$0` несоответствие, бросает ошибку, и загрузка прекращается (а JVM падает).